# Return value while using cProfile

Tags: python

I'm trying to profile an instance method, so I've done something like:

```
import cProfile

class Test():

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def method(self):
        cProfile.runctx("self.method_actual()", globals(), locals())

    def method_actual(self):
        print "Run"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Test().method()
```

But now problems arise when I want "method" to return a value that is computed by "method_actual". I don't really want to call "method_actual" twice.

Is there another way, something that can be thread safe? (In my application, the cProfile data are saved to datafiles named by one of the args, so they don't get clobbered and I can combine them later.)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I discovered that you can do this:

```
prof = cProfile.Profile()
retval = prof.runcall(self.method_actual, *args, **kwargs)
prof.dump_stats(datafn)
```

The downside is that it's undocumented.

Comment: Brilliant! This looks perfect - but what is 'datafn'?

Comment: @JonathanHartley - The filename for the data file IIRC.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I thought 'fn' meant function, not filename.

Comment: @Ngoral it's just a file name. You can put whatever name you like there.

Comment: @Ngoral no worries, I should clarify in the answer

Answer (score 31):

An option for any arbitrary code:

```
import cProfile, pstats, sys
pr = cProfile.Profile()
pr.enable()

my_return_val = my_func(my_arg)

pr.disable()
ps = pstats.Stats(pr, stream=sys.stdout)
ps.print_stats()
```

Taken from https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html#profile.Profile

Comment: You could even make a little context manager for that using `contextlib`s `contextmanager` decorator.

Comment: I get `Random listing order was used` - how can I specify listing order ?

Comment: ps.sort_stats('cumulative')

Comment: how do I generate a valid profile file with this method so that I can use it with SnakeViz

Comment: I would only add something like:  ps.dump_stats('my_dumpfile.dmp')
so one can use snakeviz or similar to view the results, otherwise this worked great for me!  I was having a heckuva time getting my return values before this.

Answer (score 8):

I was struggling with the same problem and used a wrapper function to get over direct return values. Instead of

```
cP.runctx("a=foo()", globals(), locales())
```

I create a wrapper function

```
def wrapper(b):
  b.append(foo())
```

and profile the call to the wrapper function

```
b = []
cP.runctx("wrapper(b)", globals(), locals())
a = b[0]
```

extracting the result of foo's computation from the out param (b) afterwards.

Answer (score 4):

I created a decorator:

```
import cProfile
import functools
import pstats

def profile(func):

    @functools.wraps(func)
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        profiler = cProfile.Profile()
        profiler.enable()
        try:
            retval = func(*args, **kwargs)
        finally:
            profiler.disable()
            with open('profile.out', 'w') as profile_file:
                stats = pstats.Stats(profiler, stream=profile_file)
                stats.print_stats()
        return retval

    return inner
```

Decorate your function or method with it:

```
@profile
def somefunc(...):
   ...
```

Now that function will be profiled.

Alternatively, if you'd like the raw, unprocessed profile data (e.g. because you want to run the excellent graphical viewer RunSnakeRun on it), then:

```
import cProfile
import functools
import pstats

def profile(func):

    @functools.wraps(func)
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        profiler = cProfile.Profile()
        profiler.enable()
        try:
            retval = func(*args, **kwargs)
        finally:
            profiler.disable()
            profiler.dump_stats('profile.out')
        return retval

    return inner
```

This is a minor improvement on several of the other answers on this page.

Answer (score 2):

I think @detly the `.runcall()` is basically the best answer, but for completeness, I just wanted to take @ThomasH 's answer to be function independent:

```
def wrapper(b, f, *myargs, **mykwargs):
    try:
        b.append(f(*myargs, **mykwargs))
    except TypeError:
        print 'bad args passed to func.'

# Example run
def func(a, n):
    return n*a + 1

b = []
cProfile.runctx("wrapper(b, func, 3, n=1)", globals(), locals())
a = b[0]
print 'a, ', a
```