# Profiling Python generators

Tags: python, profiling, profiler, web.py

I'm adapting an application that makes heavy use of generators to produce its results to provide a web.py web interface.

So far, I could wrap the call to the for-loop and the output-producing statements in a function and call that using `cProfile.run()` or `runctx()`. Conceptually:

```
def output():
    for value in generator():
        print(value)

cProfile.run('output()')
```

In web.py, I have to wrap it the following way, since I want to immediately produce output from the potentially long-running computation in each iteration step using `yield`:

```
class index:
    def GET(self):
        for value in generator():
            yield make_pretty_html(value)
```

Is there a way to profile all calls to the generator like in the first example when it's used like in the second one?

Comment: Do you simply want to measure the whole function call instead of just one iteration? As in `cProfile.run('list(index().GET())')` ?

Comment: In essence, this is what the for-loop accomplishes. The problem here is that I have no control over calls to `GET()`, it's handled by `web.py`. Furthermore, I don't think output would get produced that way anymore (using the return value).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally found a solution. Return value of profiling via [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584425/return-value-while-using-cprofile).

```
import cProfile
import pstats
import glob
import math

def gen():
    for i in range(1, 10):
        yield math.factorial(i)

class index(object):
    def GET(self):
        p = cProfile.Profile()

        it = gen()
        while True:
            try:
                nxt = p.runcall(next, it)
            except StopIteration:
                break
            print nxt

        p.print_stats()

index().GET()
```

I also could merge multiple such profiling results (once I start giving unique file names) via [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html#pstats.Stats.add) and store/analyze them combined.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're trying to profile each call to 'next' on the generator? If so, you could wrap your generator in a profiling generator. Something like this, where the commented off part will be sending the results to a log or database.

```
def iter_profiler(itr):
  itr = iter(itr)
  while True:
    try:
      start = time.time()
      value = itr.next()
      end = time.time()
    except StopIteration:
      break
    # do something with (end - stop) times here
    yield value
```

Then instead of instantiating your generator as `generator()` you would use `iter_profiler(generator())`

Comment: alternatively, you could apply a modified version of it as a decorator at the definition of the generator.

Comment: Basically, you're right. I already do count the milliseconds between before and after the `for` loop in my original post's second example, so I already have this information (although I count a bit more than you would, but a few millis don't matter). However, I care more for the "hot spots" in my code (where does computing time go to die?) than exactly which of the dozens of results took longer than the others. Therefore I was hoping for a `profile/cProfile` based solution (that does not generate one report per result). If there's a way to merge profiler reports, that would be the way to go.

Comment: For anyone looking at this solution in python3.x, note that generators no long have a `next()` method, use the free function (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21622193/python-3-2-coroutine-attributeerror-generator-object-has-no-attribute-next/21622696) instead.  This is done in the above answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use time.time() to profile the parts you are interested in? Just get the current time and subtract from the last time you made a measurement.

Comment: I already get the total timing, but "Processing took 5.382 seconds" isn't specific enough for finding performance bottlenecks. I use a rather large and branching chain of generators internally and intended to store user input and resulting performance for later analysis. I have several functions that take an average 0.000 seconds each call but might be called tens of thousands of times.

Comment: In that case you can have an integer counter for every execution of those functions and only do a measurement every 1000th execution? You could measure chunks of code this way instead and narrow down the bottlenecks. I realize it may be a bit tedious, depending on the code.