# Python Script Takes Too Long to Run

Tags: python, performance, large-files

I am seeking general guidance on how to process large file (will millions of rows in it) quickly and general advice on how to approach this as well as improve the code. I assume the last part where line by line is written to the file is not optimal but I am not so sure how to approach it i.e. what would be the fastest way and mechanisms behind it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
import csv
import json
import pandas as pd

filename = 'filename.csv'

def getstuff():
    with open(filename, "rt") as csvfile:
        datareader = csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter="|")
        for row in datareader:
            yield row[8]

def get_json():
    with open('bad_records.txt', 'w') as f:  # Open the bad records file
        for i in getstuff():
            if '"metrics"' in i:
                try:
                    yield json.loads(i)
                except json.JSONDecodeError:
                    f.write(f"{i}\n")

def make_dataframe():
    for i in get_json():
        yield pd.json_normalize(i["metrics"])

with open('name.txt',mode="a") as f:
    for df in make_dataframe():
        df.to_csv(f, index=False, header=False, sep='\t',escapechar='\\')
```

Comment: Did you profile the individual steps?

Comment: *I assume the last part where line by line is written to the file is not optimal* - you can try skipping it entirely for a test (so the `df.to_csv` would be a `pass`). My bet goes for reading JSON-embedded-in-kinda-CSV being the slow part.

Comment: @jarmod I have done it for the first functions and that one at least with cProfile.run()  offers quickly some results (all zeroes but then again I might be doing something wrong) but the last one takes too much time so I must say I have not profiled it in fullest. Any advice on profiling that I missed?

Comment: Some ideas for [profiling Python generator functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570335/profiling-python-generators). Alternatively, try as suggested by @tevemadar by replacing actual functionality by pass to determine the delta.

Comment: I think this could be parallelized using [Dask delayed](https://examples.dask.org/applications/embarrassingly-parallel.html#Use-Dask-Delayed-to-make-our-function-lazy).  If you provide examples for your input data files I could have a go at it.

Comment: @jarmod thanks for the post about the profiling! It is really helpful! So the first two functions ran and I got the statistics. However, the one where dataframe is created takes a lot of time. I will assume that is where improvement needs to happen.