# How to determine latency of a GET request, in python

Tags: python, web-crawler, latency

```
import subprocess

host = "yahoo.com"

ping = subprocess.Popen(
    ["ping", "-c", "3", host],
    stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr = subprocess.PIPE
)

out, error = ping.communicate()
print out
```

So far I have this for a ping test to a server

basically:

Take a look at this,

Everytime I look want to look up prices of products, i send a HTTP GET request with the product details to f3's API. I am trying to determine how long it takes to retrieve the product price information after receiving my call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question well, but if I'm right, what you want can be achieved using the `time` function from the `time` module, which returns the number of seconds elapsed since EPOCH:

```
from time import time

time_before = time()
perform_get() # whatever way you do this
time_after = time()
time_taken = time_after-time_before

print time_taken
```

Comment: As of Python 3.3, you should use [`time.perf_counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter) for more precise measurements.

Answer (score 5):

If you need only HTTP ping, you can use the excellent Python library, `requests`

```
import requests, json

def call_some_api (params) :
    """ You can track time of any your API call. """

    result = requests.get("rest-api-endpoint.com")
        # Now result contains all request data you need


    print "Call time:", result.elapsed # .. prints timedelta ..
    json_result = json.load( result.text ) # Here are RESTful API, JSON response

    return json_result
```

For more information you can see [requests docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)

If you looking for timing some action in general, you can use [this simple decorators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5375728/225767)

For current python, use `print(f'Call time: {result.elapsed}')`

Optionally, use `result.elapsed.total_seconds()`

See [How to measure server response time for Python requests POST-request](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43252542/7758804)