# How to measure server response time for Python requests POST-request

Tags: python, python-3.x, server, network-programming, python-requests

I create POST requests with `requests` as follows, with a specified `timeout` threshold:

`response = requests.post(url, data=post_fields, timeout=timeout)`

However, to determine a "good" `threshold`, I need to benchmark the server response times.

How do I compute the minimum and maximum response times for the server?

Comment: check out `contextmanager` you can wrap it around a simple function which takes the elapsed time instead of having to write a whole new decorator

Answer (score 267, accepted):

The `Response` object returned by `requests.post()` (and `requests.get()` etc.) has a property called `elapsed`, which provides the time delta between the `Request` was sent and the `Response` was received. To get the delta in seconds, use the `total_seconds()` method:

```
response = requests.post(url, data=post_fields, timeout=timeout)
print(response.elapsed.total_seconds())
```

Note that `requests.post()` is a synchronous operation, which means that it **blocks** until the `Response` is received.

Comment: Just want to add `elapsed` is available on any `Response`, not just responses from `POST` requests.

Comment: Notice that this won't get you the time it takes to download the response from the server, but only the time it takes until you get the return headers without the response contents. If you want the elapsed time to include the time it takes to download the response you'll have to use time.clock()

Comment: However, it disappoints that `elapsed` is not available when an error occurs, including ordinary read timeouts, when the ability to measure execution time would be a reasonable expectation.

Comment: @mirekphd I get your point, but for a read timeout, no response is ever received

Answer (score 30):

It depends on whether you can hit the server with a lot of test requests, or whether you need to wait for real requests to occur.

If you need real request data, then you'd need to wrap the call to determine the time of each request:

```
start = time.perf_counter()
response = requests.post(url, data=post_fields, timeout=timeout)
request_time = time.perf_counter() - start
self.logger.info("Request completed in {0:.0f} seconds".format(request_time))
#store request_time in persistent data store
```

You'd need somewhere to store the results of each request over a period of time (file, database, etc). Then you can just calculate the stats of the response times.

If you have a test server available, you could benchmark the response without python using something like apachebench and sending test data for each request:

https://gist.github.com/kelvinn/6a1c51b8976acf25bd78

Comment: The `time.clock()` function has been removed in Python 3.8. The preferred replacement appears to be `time.perf_counter()`.